# Need to parse the XML starting from a specific element using Sax XML

Tags: java, xml, sax

Hopefully someone can help and its simple fix. My code is below with the current output from running the code.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName , String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if(!localName.matches("characterID")) {
        String Primary = attributes.getValue("characterID");
        System.out.println("ROOAR:" + Primary);

    } else {
       System.out.println("ROOAR:" + localName);
    }


Output
    ROOAR:null
    ROOAR:null
    ROOAR:null
    ROOAR:null
    ROOAR:92916469
    ROOAR:95325415
    ROOAR:95528725
    ROOAR:null
```

I want to know how i can be specific where the startElement is at a specified child element. As of right now it starts off at the root element but i rather it start on line 5 were it has its own child element.

Sample xml

```
           <eveapi version="2">
           <currentTime>2015-08-14 22:44:09</currentTime>
           <result>
           <rowset name="characters" key="characterID" columns="name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName">
           <row name="Grasume" characterID="95528725" corporationName="School of Applied Knowledge" corporationID="1000044" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" />
           </rowset>
           </result>
           <cachedUntil>2015-08-14 23:03:33</cachedUntil>
           </eveapi>
```

Comment: Add the sample input in your question. It'll help to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

When using SAX event-based parsing, you will have to keep track of your current parse state, i.e. depth or path, using the events provided, namely `startElement`.

First, track that your "root" was entered, then the various levels in the path, and when you enter the path you are interested in, you can at that point process the attributes and sub-elements.